# Encrypt application data and only application know the key

Tags: encryption

I need to encrypt application data stored in database. Application should generate encryption key, and only application should know this key. Also I need to deploy multiple instances of application, and key should be the same.

What tools to use to achieve that?

Comment: It is trivial to extract the key from the application. What attack are you attempting to defend from? Some positions are to be avoided as they can not be defended.

Comment: Application generate a key and store it in RAM. Is it possible to extract it?

Comment: I want that even administrator of database can't to get the real data, only encrypted version.

Comment: @DanD.It well may not be "trivial" depending on the platform, not that it is a good scheme.